# How can I define a variable which can be shared between functions defined in decl_module?

Tags: substrate

I want to implement the process below:

```
During the processing of a block:
before executing any extrinsics (on_initialize): 
  initialize MyVariable

When MyFunction is called:
  update MyVariable

end of executing all extrinsics (on_finalize):
  update a variable defined in decl_storage with MyVariable
```

So I defined three functions in `decl_module`: `on_initialize`, `MyFunction` , and `on_finalize`.
But how can I define `MyVariable`, which will be initialized in `on_initialize`, and then updated in `MyFunction` , and finally in `on_finalize` it will be used to update a variable defined in `decl_storage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a `decl_storage` storage item for that variable, or simply update the existing storage during each step since you will push the value in `on_finalize` anyway.

You can see the use of transient storage items in pallets like Timestamp:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/timestamp/src/lib.rs#L191

Where `DidUpdate` is set somewhere earlier in the block, and removed during the `on_finalize`.